# Transiting through Panama to Port of Spain

Tags: transit, panama

I am an Indian Passport holder, my ticket to Port of Spain is as follows:
21Jun: DEL-AMS-PTY on KLM -> arrival @ 1645
21Jun: PTY-POS on CM (Copa Airlines)-> departure @ 1909

Amadeus CRS PNR is one, but the ticket has been issued separately. I can see KLM Ticket 074-xxxxxxx044 and CM Ticket 230-xxxxxxx049

Do I require Panama Transit/Tourist visa, as this will not be mine thru check in right? my baggage/luggage will be out at Panama and again I have to recheck at Panama for Port of Spain.

Please suggest/advise, will there be any problem with my travelling.

Answer (score 1):

Any traveller transiting through Panama's Tocumen Airport (PTY) does not need a special visa in the following circumstances:

- The period between flights is less than 9 hours
- You do not leave through Tocumen Airport Immigration gates into Panama City.

If your layover is ever longer than 9 hours, talk to your airline about any special requirements before booking. The safe route here would be to apply to a tourist visa, though. If you have more than 9 hours to spend in Panama City, it's doable! Panama City is rather small and accessible, and also deals in USD.

In your case, it seems your flight is (was) fine for transit without a visa.

Comment: Normally one has to go through immigration when they are required to get their baggage and recheck it.